# Deploying Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator Application

Tags: windows, mobile, emulation

I am deploying a C# mobile application developed in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 with the help of Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK under the Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator.

Unfortunately, even if the Build is successful (no errors) the application is never deployed logically or physically on the emulator (the application is neither started on the emulator and also the application cannot be found anywhere in Programs or on the emulator file-system).

I would be happy to provide any additional information in case needed.

Comment: Do you have all the requisite software installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a breakpoint and run it in the debugger.  Make sure you are connected to the Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator.